# Python3.9 malloc: can't allocate region error 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, macos, numpy

I am using Python3.9 and I started writing a simple script to shape some data, I tested it after writing just a single line and I am getting this error:

```
 $ Python3.9 Shape_Response.py 
Python(2857,0x1061635c0) malloc: can't allocate region
*** mach_vm_map(size=18446744072478715904) failed (error code=3)
Python(2857,0x1061635c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
init_dgelsd failed init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dominik/Desktop/Google Analytics API/Shape_Response.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd, numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

This is the Python script:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter = "\n", header=None)

print(df)
```

The file I am reading is:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

I am on MacOs.

Details of my Python installation are:

```sh
dominik at Dominiks-MacBook-Pro in Google Analytics API
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

dominik at Dominiks-MacBook-Pro in Google Analytics API
$ python --version
>>> Python 3.9.0

dominik at Dominiks-MacBook-Pro in Google Analytics API
$ pip --version
>>> pip 20.2.4 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

dominik at Dominiks-MacBook-Pro in Google Analytics API
$ pip list
>>> Package         Version
>>> --------------- -------
>>> numpy           1.19.2
>>> pandas          1.1.3
>>> pip             20.2.4
>>> python-dateutil 2.8.1
>>> pytz            2020.1
>>> setuptools      49.2.1
>>> six             1.15.0
>>> wheel           0.35.1
```

I installed pandas using `pip install wheel` and `pip install pandas`.

I also have free memory, I reinstalled my Python and I am still running into this error.

I am a Python beginner and I really don't understand the error message, I tried searching but nothing worked...

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: I had the same error (OSX and Python@3.9). My only resolution was to downgrade to Python@3.8. I think it's being worked on - https://bugs.python.org/issue40928

Comment: If you're doing data analysis, consider downloading Anaconda. Does all the legwork for you in terms of downloading pandas and numpy and all dependencies and packages them all together.

Answer (score 3):

brew is not yet stable for MacOS BIG SUR as on date.
I upgraded to Python 3.9 and faced same issue with numpy mem allocations, so i rolled back like this:

```
brew link --overwrite python@3.8
  Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2... 25 symlinks created

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

this way I am back on Python 3.8.6 which works fine

Comment: update - now it works, am currently on 3.9 facing no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue was for me when I install python3.8/3.9 using brew.
I got around this problem by deleting brew version of python and install python from [python.org/mac-osx](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/)

Answer (score 2):

I was also having issues with getting `numpy` to work on my machine.

## Context

My setup is MacOS Big Sur running the zsh command line using the `oh-my-zsh` extension. I was having issues with importing `numpy` ever since I upgraded from Catalina to Big Sur.

I had a few versions of Python3 installed on my machine:

- Python3.9 (brew)
- Python3.8 (brew)
- Python3.8 (from [python.org](http://python.org) I think)

with the `python3` alias pointing to one of the `brew` versions of Python, at least according to the output of performing the command `which python3`. I believe that these `brew` versions were installed automatically as dependencies for another program.

Since I had multiple versions of Python installed, I believe that I had multiple paths pointing to the same `python`/`python3` alias. To solve this issue, I first removed any old Python paths which could have been automatically created whenever I installed a new version of Python (either through brew or official release).

## My Steps

I took the following steps to fix my supposed issue. If your issue sounds similar to mine, this may be helpful!

#### Part A. Clearing out `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`

1. Type into the command line: `vi ~/.bashrc` and remove anything that contains something along the lines of `export PATH=/usr/...<some more directories>...python:%PATH`.
2. Type into the command line: `vi ~/.zshrc` and follow the same process as before.

#### Part B. Removing `brew`-installed versions of Python

Next, I removed any versions of `python` which were installed by `brew`. Since I had both Python3.9 and Python3.8, I used the following commands to uninstall them via `brew`:

1. `brew uninstall python@3.9`
2. `brew uninstall python@3.8`

#### Part C. Installing a fresh version of Python

Once the `brew` versions of Python were uninstalled, running the command `which python3` now pointed to the Python3.8 version I had installed from [python.org](http://python.org). Since I wanted to run a different version of Python, I went over to the [python downloads page for Mac OS X](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) and downloaded the [Mac OS X 64-bit installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-390/).

After doing so and restarting my terminal, running the `which python3` command now pointed to the latest version of Python which I installed.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

You should also run `which pip3` to confirm that `pip3` is aliased to the proper version of pip to use for Python3.9, which should be the case if installing Python via the installer.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3
```

#### Part D. Installing `numpy`

Once `python3` and `pip3` are set up, you can run `pip3 install numpy`, which should install a fresh version of `numpy` for Python3.9. Then, running an import statement for `numpy` (such as `import numpy as np`) inside of a `.py` file should work with no issues.

## Conclusion

I am sure that this is not the best way of handling different version of Python, but it worked for me and I hope it works for you as well. Overall though, this may be a good workaround for now until someone figures out a better way or if `numpy` fixes this in a future update.

I have heard that using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) are good ways of dealing with multiple environments and versions of Python. This may be helpful for you. Good luck!

- Edit: Added a section on `pip3` aliasing and a section on the result after installing `numpy`.
- Edit: Added information on where the multiple versions of Python I had on my machine may have originated from.

Comment: Update: After this "fix", I had kept getting issues with other libraries, such as `OpenCV`, so be warned that it might not be perfect. I instead went with uninstalling all versions of Python I had on my machine, and installed Python via [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/). No issues since then!

Answer (score 1):

I just had same issue on Python 3.9.2 installed using [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/).

I noticed that you had version 1.19.2 numpy installed, I had 1.19.4 installed and upgrading to numpy 1.20.1 solved the problem for me.